# Write Pandas DataFrame to String Buffer with Chunking

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I have a 10k row csv that I want to write to s3 in chunks of 1k rows.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

csv_buffer = StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer, chunksize=1000)
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'df.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

This gives me the first 1k rows in a string buffer to write to s3, but it doesn't seem like csv buffer is an iterator that i can loop over.

anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: did the answer help you to find the solution? I have a similar problem, I am curious how you resolved it in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `StringIO` isn't really heeding the chunksize.  (`.readlines()` will always just return one line, never a chunk of lines.)

I'm not too familiar with boto3, but `itertools.islice` may work for you here in terms of needing to slice an iterable without creating some intermediate data structure.

If this looks like it may suit your needs, I can add some explanation alongside the code:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
... from itertools import islice
... import sys
... 
... import numpy as np
... import pandas as pd
... 
... df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(300).reshape(100, -1))
... csv_buffer = StringIO()
... df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
... csv_buffer.seek(0)
... 
... # Account for indivisibility (scoop up a remainder on the final slice).
... chunksize = 33
... rowsize = df.shape[1]
... slices = [(0, chunksize)] * (rowsize - 1) + [(0, sys.maxsize)]
... chunks = (tuple(islice(csv_buffer, i, j)) for i, j in slices)
... 

>>> next(chunks)
(',0,1,2\n',
 '0,0,1,2\n',
 '1,3,4,5\n',
 '2,6,7,8\n',
 '3,9,10,11\n',
 '4,12,13,14\n',
 '5,15,16,17\n',
 '6,18,19,20\n',
 '7,21,22,23\n',
 '8,24,25,26\n',
 '9,27,28,29\n',
 '10,30,31,32\n',
 '11,33,34,35\n',
 '12,36,37,38\n',
 '13,39,40,41\n',
 '14,42,43,44\n',
 '15,45,46,47\n',
 '16,48,49,50\n',
 '17,51,52,53\n',
 '18,54,55,56\n',
 '19,57,58,59\n',
 '20,60,61,62\n',
 '21,63,64,65\n',
 '22,66,67,68\n',
 '23,69,70,71\n',
 '24,72,73,74\n',
 '25,75,76,77\n',
 '26,78,79,80\n',
 '27,81,82,83\n',
 '28,84,85,86\n',
 '29,87,88,89\n',
 '30,90,91,92\n',
 '31,93,94,95\n')
```